# ESBuild error: No loader is configured for ".node" files: node_modules/sharp/build/Release/sharp.node

Tags: node.js, sharp, esbuild

I am trying to make an `esbuild` plugin that converts GIF to PNG using Sharp but I get the following error:

> ❯ npx esbuild .\src\utils\gif-to-png.ts --platform=node --bundle
> node_modules/sharp/lib/utility.js:7:22: error: No loader is configured for ".node" files: node_modules/sharp/build/Release/sharp.node
> 7 │ const sharp = require('../build/Release/sharp.node');
> ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

## gif-to-png.ts

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import sharp from 'sharp'
import { Plugin } from 'esbuild'

const ROOT_PATH = process.cwd()
const POSTS_PATH = path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'public')

function* walkSync(dir: fs.PathLike): any {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(dir, { withFileTypes: true })
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
            yield* walkSync(path.join(dir as string, files[i].name))
        } else {
            yield path.join(dir as string, files[i].name)
        }
    }
}

const gifToPng = async () => {
    try {
        for (let [i, file] of [...walkSync(POSTS_PATH)].entries()) {
            const extname = path.extname(file)
            if (extname === '.gif') {
                console.log(file)
                const dirname = path.dirname(file)
                const png = path.resolve(dirname, path.basename(file).replace('.gif', '.png'))
                await sharp(file).png().toFile(png)
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error thrown:', e)
    }
}

export const gifToPngPlugin = (): Plugin => ({
    name: 'gifToPng',
    setup(build) {
        build.onLoad({ filter: /\.gif$/ }, async (args) => {
            const fileName = path.basename(args.path, '.gif')
            let contents = await fs.promises.readFile(args.path, 'utf8')
            console.log({ fileName, contents })

            return {
                contents,
                loader: 'file',
            }
        })
    },
})
```

My code is still a work in progress but I have to somehow call `gifToPng` function in the `setup` so it converts all `.gif` files to `.png`.

How do I solve the `.node` loader issue?

## Edit:

Turns out, ESBuild doesn't support `.node` yet -> https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/1051

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue. I added this line to my build config object. Probably better explanation in the docs: https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#file

```
build({    
  loader: { ".node": "file" },
  ...
})
```

Comment: what does this does?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but, based on the docs it should change the loader type for exernal file for all `.node` files. There is also a `copy` loader which copies the file into the bundle and rewrites the import paths. File loader should only copy the file and import the file as string, where the `copy` file loader alters this import eg. loader: file -> `"./example.json"` and loder: copy -> `"./example-PVCBWCM4.json"`. Probably hashes in the filename for some cache validation makes a problem in this case. But this is just my assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Accordig to esBuild https://esbuild.github.io/getting-started/#bundling-for-node

> You also may not want to bundle your dependencies with esbuild. There are many node-specific features that esbuild doesn't support while bundling such as `__dirname`, `import.meta.url`, `fs.readFileSync`, and `*.node` native binary modules. You can exclude all of your dependencies from the bundle by setting packages to external.

> `esbuild app.jsx --bundle --platform=node --packages=external`

I resolved the same issue by adding `--packages=external`

```
build({    
  loader: { "packages": "external" },
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/getsentry/profiling-node/issues/189) and [the docs](https://github.com/getsentry/profiling-node#bundling) for bundling Sentry, the `copy` loader should be used:

```js
build({    
  loader: { ".node": "copy" },
})
```